# org.apache.commons.math3.linear.SingularMatrixException: matrix is singular

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cloudera

I am performing time series forecasting for a set of values using cloudera library **com.cloudera.sparkts** .

```
var model = ARIMA.fitModel(1,0,2,mySeries)
model.forecast(newSeries,10)
```

While performing this, I am getting an exception as shown below :

```
ERROR Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 5255488 bytes, TID = 12
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 12)
org.apache.commons.math3.linear.SingularMatrixException: matrix is singular
at org.apache.commons.math3.linear.QRDecomposition$Solver.solve(QRDecomposition.java:354)
```

Before passing the series to the model , I am checking whether the series is having the same value and if the values are same, I am not performing the operation.

Is there anyway, I can solve this exception?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `singular` here means that your series has one value, but that the solution [Matrix is Singular](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularMatrix.html).

In other words, your equation (fitting) has no real solutions.

Comment: The first statement itself where the model is evaluated from the series is breaking during execution. So is there anyway, I can avoid this  by checking the series ?

Comment: @rvp I'm really not familiar with `ARIMA`. I would try limiting the series length to a larger number, or search for a method similar to `ARIMA.isModelFittable`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to apply various models to a number of series and in between , I was getting this exception and my execution was breaking.

There is no functionality available in Cloudera time-series library to check if a model can be fit to a time series collection. So I controlled this exception by catching the exception and ignoring those models. So even if some models were not fit to the series , I was able to make it fit to some other models by ignoring the breaking ones.

```
var model1Passed = true
try{
     var model1 = ARIMA.fitModel(1,0,1,series)
   }
catch{
     case _: Throwable => model1Passed = false
   }
```

Once you create the model , you can check the model compatibility by checking the AIC (Akaike information criterion) values as shown below :

```
val AICval = model1.approxAIC(series)
```

Smaller the values of AIC indicates better the model.